# parentheses of numbering got lost after \counterwithout command

Tags: numbering, linguistics, linguex

In `linguex` package, I want a continuous numbering of examples across chapters, thus I added the command `\counterwithout{ExNo}{chapter}`. However, the parentheses of the numbering got lost in the second chapter.

[image]

I have tried the command `\newcommand{\theExLBr}{(} \newcommand{\theExRBr}{)}` to customize the style, but overleaf simply wouldn't allow it to operate.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{linguex} %for examples sentences and glosses
\counterwithout{ExNo}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{s}

\ex. 
\a. This is 1a. \label{1a}
\b. this is 1b. \label{1b}
\par

 This is \ref{1a}.

\chapter{ss}

\ex. \label{e2} This is the second example.
\par
\ex. \label{e3} This is the third example.
\par

\ref{e2} and \ref{e3} have no parentheses, but \ref{1a} does.

\end{document}
```

I wonder if there is some way to get the parentheses back.

Answer (score 2):

The `\counterwithout{ExNo}{chapter}` not only removes the counter from the reset list of `chapter`, but also redefines `\theExNo` to `\arabic{ExNo}`.

In order that the redefinition is not performed, you should do

```
\counterwithout*{ExNo}{chapter}
```

Complete example

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for smaller pictures

\usepackage{linguex} %for examples sentences and glosses

\counterwithout*{ExNo}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{s}

\ex. 
\a. This is 1a. \label{1a}
\b. this is 1b. \label{1b}
\par

 This is \ref{1a}.

\chapter{ss}

\ex. \label{e2} This is the second example.
\par
\ex. \label{e3} This is the third example.
\par

\ref{e2} and \ref{e3} have no parentheses, but \ref{1a} does.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some comments are in order. The `\counterwithout*` command *doesn't* redefine the representation of the counter, which *in this case* is what's needed, because the initial definition of `\theExNo` is

```
\theExLBr\arabic{ExNo}\theExRBr
```

and it should not be touched.

In other use cases of `\counterwithout{counterA}{counterB}`, redefining `\thecounterA` is likely necessary, because it might contain references to `\thecounterB`.

Looking at the definition of `\thecounterA` before proceeding with `\counterwithout` is recommended.